# How to fill a form inside an iframe with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Well, I already researched and found a similar question in the stack overflow but I didn't understand it and therefore I did it wrong and it didn't work, I have the following script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');  
const fs = require('fs').promises;                                                                                                              
(async () => {
 console.log("Iniciado!")                        
 const browser = await 
 puppeteer.launch({        
  executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium',            
  headlesss:false,                                
 });                                             
 const page = await 
 browser.newPage();           
 await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });                                          await  
 page.setRequestInterceptiontrue);
 page.on('request', (req) => {                   
  if(req.resourceType() === 'image' || req.resourceType() === 'stylesheet' || req.resourceType() === 'font'){
   req.abort();                                   
  }                                               
  else {                                           
   req.continue();                               
  }                                              
 });
 await page.goto('https://www.nike.com.br/chuteira-nike-premier-2-sala-unissex-153-169-171-309321', { waitUntil: 'load',timeout:0});             
 await page.waitForXPath('//label[@for="tamanho__idM40F395"]',{visibility:true, timeout:0});    
 const tamanho = await page.$x('//label[@for="tamanho__idM40F395"]')                             
 await tamanho[0].click('//label[@for="tamanho__idM40F395"]');
 await page.waitForSelector('button#anchor-acessar-unite-oauth2')
 await page.click('button#anchor-acessar-unite-oauth2')
 })();
```

Run this script, it will select the sneaker size and click on the login button, but how can I fill out the form if it is inside the iframe?  I need to be able to complete the form.

**Note:**

I removed the image and css loading for the page to load faster.

Comment: "I found a similar question in the stack overflow but I didn't understand it" -- could you provide a link to this? Perhaps we can help you understand it, and this provides useful context.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find the iframe element, get its frame and use it instead of the page:

```js
const iframe = await page.waitForSelector('iframe#nike-unite-oauth2-iframe')
const frame = await iframe.contentFrame()
await frame.type('input[name="emailAddress"]', 'foo@bar.com')
await frame.type('input[name="password"]', '123')
await frame.click('input[value="ENTRAR"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the puppeteer type api? from what i can see, your email and pw fields are input fields with ids. Try this `await page.type('#88650c48-8f4f-48b7-9ce3-48087cacfd1c', 'my_email')` same goes for password field.

Comment: <iframe> shouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: I was trying to click on the input and after that insert some text and it didn't work, testing your example didn't work because the id of the input is dynamic, the name of the input is not dynamic anymore how can I fill in using the name property?